# How to redirect html to dialer with call number *123#

Tags: javascript, android, html, reactjs, angular

Good day all. I have a simple link on a webpage, in where the user can call an USSD number:

```
<a href="tel:*123#" class="phoneCallButtonLink">*CLICK HERE AND CALL *123#</a>
```

in Android phone when testing this page, the phone (or something) stripped out the last "#" (only the last) from the link, resulting in a call to *123.

and in Iphone series not open dialer.

does anyone has experienced this? or knows how to prevent this?

i try use :

```
<a href="tel:*123%23">#224</a>
```

or

```
window.location = "tel:*111*2" + Uri.encode("#");
```

but not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="tel:*123%23">#224</a>
```

This works well, but it should run on the phone, not on the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="tel:123-456-7890">CLICK TO CALL</a>
```

try this it will work and **replace #** to **%23** and it will work

```
<a href="tel:%23 224">CLICK TO CALL #224</a>
```